# Minimum existence in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, maxima-minima

I am trying to understand if this statement holds true:

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a coercive and lower semicontinuous function. Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus exists
$$\min_{x\in [a, +\infty)} F(x).$$

In my opinion it holds true since we are in a particular case of this more general result:

${\bf Theorem:}$ Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and $K\subset H, K\neq\emptyset$ be a closed and convex subset. If $F:H\to\mathbb{R}$ is a weakly lower semicontinuous and coercive functional. Thus $\min_{u\in K} F(u)$ exists.

In my case $H$ is a Hilbert space of dimension $1$ (so weak and strong convergence coincide) and $[a, +\infty)$ is a closed and convex subset.

Could someone please help me to understand if my reasoning holds true or am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: It is true. As the function is coercive, you can restrict to a compact interval (as it grows when it goes to infinity). Lower semicontinuous functions attain their minimum on compact sets.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, you mean that since it holds in each compact $[a, b], b\in\mathbb{R}$, thus (intuitively) screwing $b\to +\infty$ it holds too, isn't it?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven and if I correctly understand, it holds true also if I replace $[a, +\infty)$ with the whole $\mathbb{R}$, it holds true, isn' it?

Comment: What I mean, is that by definition of coercive there exists $R>0$ such that $f(x)>f(0)$ for $\vert x \vert >R$. Thus, we have $$ \inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}} F(x) = \inf_{x\in [-R,R]} F(x). $$ Hence, all we need to show is that $F$ admits a minimum on the compact interval $[-R,R]$.